# Where should I put the apostrophe for the word positions?

Tags: apostrophe

> I feel that my skill set and personality fit the positions responsibilities and requirements perfectly.

is it:
position's
positions
or positions'

My best guess is position's because of ownership.. But I am not 100%. Its for a cover letter for a job so id like to get it right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Position's" is correct but ugly and clumsy. Rewrite the sentence with a preposition: "…perfectly fit the requirements and responsibilities of the position".